# Parse additional data in push notification by OneSingal by flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, onesignal

Please help me for this case. I implement feature - push notification by OneSignal.
My situation as belows:

**Android devices:**

- Receive notification:

  - App close: open push, navigate to specific Page I set. OK
  - App open, run in background: open push, navigate to specific Page I set. OK

**IOS devices:**

- Receive notification:

  - App close: open push, only open app, not go to specific page. **NOT GOOD**
  - App open, run in background: open push, navigate to specific Page I set. OK

My snippet code:

**HomePage.dart**

```
void initState() {
    _bloc = getCurrentBloc<HomeBloc>();
    OneSignalWapper.handleClickNotification(context);
//    OneSignalWapper.handleReceiveNotification(context);
    super.initState();
}
```

**OneSignalWapper.dart**

```
  static void handleClickNotification(BuildContext context) {
    OneSignal.shared
        .setNotificationOpenedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result) async {
      try {
        var postId = await result.notification.payload.additionalData["post_id"];
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => PostDetailsScreen.newInstance('$postId')));
      } catch (e, stacktrace) {
        log(e);
      }
    });
  }
```

Most of test cases are worked already. There is only one case: IOS, close APP (NOT GOOD case above).
How can I fix it. Please give some advices. 
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

final GlobalKey navigatorKey = new GlobalKey();

```
    OneSignal.shared.setNotificationOpenedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
  print('BİLDİRİM AÇILDI İŞLEYİCİ İLE ÇAĞRILANMIŞTIR: ${result}');

  navigatorKey.currentState!.push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => YourPage(),
    ),
  );


});
```

**MaterialApp
navigatorKey: navigatorKey,**